# Internet Explorer PNG CSS Problem with Opacity

Tags: css, png

I have a very strange problem that I cannot seem to overcome. When I overlay text on top of a to that have a PNG image and also has an Opacity, the text itself becomes transparent. I've tested this in IE7, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and seems like IE 7 just will not want to work.

To see the problem, visit http://yask.me'>http://yask.me

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't work in IE8 either, and I am certain it is because you are fading the images and the fact that IE uses the `alpha` filter to do opacity changes on the fade.

If you do the following css, it seems to solve it (setting the alpha filter on the text appears to keep the text as one would expect):

```
#panMain {filter: alpha(opacity=100);}
```